# Compute $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x^{2n})$ for $|x|\lt 1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, products

Compute for $|x|\lt 1$:$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x^{2n})$$

I'm having trouble computing this product. My work ends up contradicting and saying $x$ has to equal $1$. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: All I've got is $$
\prod_{n\ge 1} (1+x^{2n})=\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{1-x^{4n}}{1-x^{2n}}=\prod_{m\ge1}\frac1{1-x^{2m+2}}
$$and that the coefficient of $x^{2k}$ is the number of partitions of $k$ into distinct integers.

Comment: [Do you expect a simple formula?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1+%2B+x%5E(2+n),+%7Bn,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D)

Comment: It can be easily shown that it is greater than $\frac1{1-x^2}$.

Comment: @gimusi And that it's at most $e^{\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}$. This won't lead to any closed-form formula, though.

Comment: @ Mike Earnest: the last expression should have a typo. The smallest power of the l.h.s. is x^2, that of your last expression starts with x^4.

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) for the generating function form. An “explicit” form for the coefficients of $x$ is given in (15) there, by substituting $Q(n)$ for the $2n$th coefficient.

Comment: See formulas in A000009 at http://oeis.org/ down under FORMULA ... for example $x^{-1/12}  \eta(x^4) / \eta(x^2)$ with the Dedekind eta function.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I understand the problem much more

Answer (score 1):

Define:

$$Q_0:=\prod_{n>0}1-q^{2n},\;Q_1:=\prod_{n>0}1+q^{2n},
\;Q_2:=\prod_{n>0}1+q^{2n-1},\;Q_3:=\prod_{n>0}1-q^{2n-1}.$$

There are many standard identities between theta functions and infinite products such as $Q_0,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3.$ For example, $1=Q_1Q_2Q_3$ and [DLMF equations 20.4.4 and 20.4.5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.4#E4).

The infinite product you want is $\;Q_1.\;$ To compute it via the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) use $\;Q_1 = (q^2,-q^2)_\infty = 1/(q^2,q^4)_\infty.\;$ The [OEIS sequence A000009](http://oeis.org/A00009) information is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\prod_{1 \leq k} \left( 1 + z^k \right)
&= \left( 1 + z^1 \right)\left( 1 + z^2 \right) \cdots \left( 1 + z^k \right) \cdots \\
&= \sum_{0 \leq n < \infty} f(n) z^n
   \quad \left| \quad
      f(n) = \left[ \begin{array}{l}
         \text{N. of partit. of $n$ into distinct parts} \\
         \text{N. of partit. of $n$ into odd parts}
      \end{array}
   \right.
\right.
\end{align*}

and unfortunately, the N. of partitions, whether as per standard definition or into distinct / odd parts, do not have any known closed generating function.

Comment: I slightly adjusted your $\LaTeX$ syntax so that the spacing in the text part is visible. Hope this is to your liking.

Comment: @SangchulLee: thanks indeed, I did not know the use of \text